# how to write method/function named movel( s, k) that moves all the elements of the 's' array to the left by 'k' positions (not rotate)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, arraylist

**this is my code below and please help me find out the the expected output[ 4,5,6,0,0,0]**

```
def movel(s, k):
  n=len(s)
  j=0
  n_arr=s[:k]
  return (s[k::]+n_arr[::])
  for j in range(0, n):
    print(s[j], end=' ')


s=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
k=3 
movel(s,k)
```

*Output : [4,5,6,1,2,3] *

Comment: What if the ```k``` is larger than the ```len(L)```?

Comment: Something like this - ```L[:] = [x for x in L[k:] ] + [0] * (len(L) - k)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do use index slicing

```py
def movel(s, k):
    if k > len(s):
        return [0] * len(s) # you decide how to handle this case
    return s[k:] + [0] * (len(s) - k)
```

Think of it this way, we change the head of the list and fill the rest with zeros.

Comment: what i will have to do to get a output from [1,2,3,4,5,6] array to  [0,0,0,1,2,3] i mean to shift right? and thank you for ur help, additionally if u kindly explain the line of code u've added cmnt  earlier.

Comment: @Sushmita we just reverse the order of things: `s[0] * (len(s) - k) + s[:k]`. The comment is about the shift is larger than your initial size list, do you want to return a list of zeros or return `None` or an error.